# Do we have a colonial world building game?

Tags: planets, warfare, physics, colonies, strategy

I was playing [From Dust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Dust) by Ubisoft when this idea come into mind.
**I wonder if there is a game that has been developed?**
(or perhaps new game can be develop) that has the following features.

**Objects and entities in the game:**

1. A universe consist of many planets.
2. Planet consist of many colonies, elements, resources, and natural forces.
3. A colony consist of many peoples (population), territory (borders), strength (power, economy and influence).
4. A player who start a colony on a planet and control elements within his colony borders.
5. Challenges, objectives and natural events occurred on the planet.

**Progression**

A player start a colony. A colony starts somewhere on a planet.

Within the borders of a colony's territory and elements that is available on that territory, the player control his colony and elements available on their territory to complete objectives and challenges of the game.

**The main objective of the game is** to grow the player's colony population and strength, broaden their territory borders, and increase his colony power & resources to conquer a planet.

By gaining enough power, energy and resources needed, a strong colony can then migrate to another planet and start another new colony.

Top players are ranked by the amount of accumulative resources, strength and influential powers they have from their colonies.

**Game physics:**
Inspired by the game From Dust. This game will embrace the concept of element control where players are given the power to control natural elements on the planet. Like earth, water, fire, wind, creatures and seeds.

**Gameplay:**
Like many existing strategy game. They may fought wars, make allies, countries etc.

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Dust

Comment: I was going to say, sounds alot like Populous. Then I looked up From Dust and found out it is the spiritual successor to Populous. Black and White is another 'god' game in a similar vein. Peter Molyneaux created both Black and White and Populous, as well as the Fable series.

Comment: actually any strategy is kinda like what you describe, just details, how deep it goes, are different and usually pretty simply rules. As example of space C&Q Stellaris, as surviving on space station Adr1ft

Comment: Computer game, board game or role playing game?

Comment: Although I answered this doesn't feel like a world building question to me. It's about suggestions for similar computer games.

Comment: Watched Adr1ft gameplay - nice space station, nice visual, but gameplay in game kinda sucks.
@dunc123 answers might get interesting for WB information, although Q is formulated so so.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Nik. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is not a discussion forum. While we do provide suggestions/recommendations for software related to worldbuilding, offering such for video games is not part of our scope.

Answer (score 3):

Universim is currently something similar to what you described. In the game you act as a 'God' where you can control your planet and stuff. I haven't investigated it much nor played it but [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrJJ1qALr6A) looks awesome. [Main website](https://theuniversim.com/) does say where the creator intends to go with it.

Comment: Awsome! ... I hope they embrace From Dust concept too

Answer (score 0):

**Spore**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spore_%282008_video_game%29

It was a huge let down of a game in my opinion. However it's scope was from single celled life to multiplanetary civilisation. Not control of elements per se but control over evolution (at least a little to begin with).

As mentioned in the comments, a lot of strategy games are ultimately very similar. Interplanetary Populous sounds appealing to me though.